# How can I integrate an ajax request into another form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I'm attempting to create a form that submits data that includes a path to an uploaded image. The form is a basic HTML form that passes information to a PHP script that interfaces with a database. The image is supposed to be uploaded with an ajax file uploader on the same page, and the resultant server filename is inserted into a hidden form field in the root form. The problem is, the ajax file upload appears to require its own form, meaning that I need to have a form within a form, which is apparently no bueno.

How can I rejigger my form so that I can have the file uploader within the bounds of the form,  yet not break everything?

Edit: code snippet:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" 
      method="post" 
      name="form">

Username: <input type='text' 
                name='username' 
                id='username' /><br>
Email: <input type="text" 
              name="email"
              id="email" /><br>
Password: <input type="password"
               name="password" 
               id="password"/><br>
Admin? <input type="checkbox"
               name="admin"
               id="admin" /><br>
File Upload: <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="upload.php">
  <input type="file" name="images[]" id="images[]" multiple />
  <button type="submit" id="btn">Upload Files!</button>
</form>

<div id="response"></div>
<ul id="image-list">
</ul>
<button id="clear" onclick="clearImgs();">Clear</button><br>
<input type="hidden" id="img-name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="newuser" id="newuser" />
<br>
<input type="button" 
       value="Register" 
       onclick="return regformhash(this.form,
                                   this.form.username,
                                   this.form.email,
                                   this.form.password);" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Absolutely no way to answer this without seeing your code.

Comment: where is your code??what is your effort so far??

Comment: Updated with relevant code snippet